# Prove $\sup(AB) = \sup(A)\sup(B)$

Tags: analysis

I know $\sup(AB) = \sup(A)\sup(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are nonnegative, but what if the assumption is dropped that $A$ and $B$ are nonnegative. Does this change the answer?

Answer (score 5):

Consider $A=[0,1]$, $B=\{-1\}$, $Sup(AB)=0$, $Sup(A)Sup(B)=-1$

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. Consider the set $$A=B=\{-1/n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}.$$
Then $\sup(AB)=sup\{ab: a\in A, b\in B\}=1$ but $sup(A)=sup(B)=0$